# How to get the current position of a particle using the JM3 Engine?

Tags: java, particles

I am in the process of creating a 3D sci-fi game. I have a nice 3D environment with asteroids, enemies, cruisers, and terrain. However, I cannot get the position of a specific particle. To be more specific:

I **can** get the initial position of where the set of particles will generate.

I **Cannot**: **Get the position of where a current specific particle is.** (Let's say it has been "fired" by a cannon a few seconds ago)

What am I attempting to do? I am trying to eventually create a particle collision detection system by getting each particle's x y and z so when a particle hits an object (like the asteroid arraylist I created named rocks) it will disappear, and other events will occur afterwards (like damage to an object, etc). I know how to create a collision system, but are clueless without a way to use a get() method to find the position of a particle.
I have checked the javadocs of the **JavaMonkey3** engine and the **env3d** engine (I am using both), but to no success.

Is this method possible, or would it just be better off to create a new .object each time a ship fires a cannon? (A .object's x,y, and z can be tracked.)
For reference, javamonkey's main particle class: http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/javadoc/index.html?com/jme3/effect/ParticleEmitter.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)  If you call getParticles()

http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/javadoc/com/jme3/effect/ParticleEmitter.html#getParticles%28%29

you should get a list of all Particles. Particles have the "position" datatype, which you can access.

http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/javadoc/com/jme3/effect/Particle.html

2) then you can iterate through your particles and check if a particle is colliding (in your implementation.